# restructure the directory structure of my netbeans web application

Tags: netbeans, web-applications, structure

I want to restructure the physical directory structure of my netbeans web application .. it must follow the maven structure can some assist me how i can do that without dependencies popping up ?

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

With `Netbeans` you can create a `Maven project` (select this instead of Web Application or something else during the project creation) like that Netbeans will create all directories `Maven` need.

Then in your `Projects View` you will not see the real directory arrangement but an ergonomic version with web pages and source.

In order to retrieve the real directory arrangement check the `Files View`.